# Doctrine 2 - Find all entities in a repository except one with a particular id value

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine 2.

I want to get all Entities of an entity class except for the one with id = 0.

I could use QueryBuilder like this:

```
// $em is EntityManager
$em->createQueryBuilder()
       ->select('c')
         ->from('Category', 'c')
           ->where('c.id <> 0')
             ->getQuery()
               ->getResult();
```

But looking at this code, it feels like too much for such a simple task.
I'm curious to know if there is any other simpler way in Doctrine for doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nop, that's how you should do it. You could omit query builder and pass entire DQL query:

```
$em->createQuery("SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE c.id != 0")->getResult();
```

Comment: Thanks. this does look better. Do u think this will also perform better than the code I posted above?

Comment: @rineez: Yes, it's slightly faster, but the difference is so small it's not worth the attention. Whenever use of query builder will make code cleaner / easier to read use query builder.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the better practice to pass the ID number, you might pass the Category object like this :

```
public function findAllExcept($category) {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('Category');
    $qb->add('select', 'c')
       ->add('from', 'Category c')
       ->add('where', 'c != :category')
       ->setParameter('category', $category);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Comment: You are not answering the actual question here. So you could post it as a comment. When you talk about better practices, A little bit of explanation about why you call it a better practice would help.

Answer (score 0):

For comparisons and conditions I recommend use Doctrine as well. It will save your time in case of switch between databases, for instance MySQL to PostgreSQL:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('c')
    ->from('Category', 'c')
    ->where($qb->expr()->neq('c.id', '?1'))
    ->setParameter('1', $category)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
```